# Doctrine: querying entities with composite foreign key

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

### Set Up

I have three entities:

- WordList
- WordInWordlist
- Definition

The WordList has a OneToMany relationship with WordInList.
The WordInList has a OneToMany relationship with Definition

---

### What I am Attempting

I am attempting to query all the definition rows where the word_id = ? and the wordlist_id = ?.

In standard SQL I would write the following:

```
SELECT * FROM definition WHERE word_wordlist_word_id = ? AND word_wordlist_wordlist_id = ?;
```

---

### Code Fragments

The applicable part of the WordInWordlist entity is blow:

```
class WordInWordlist
{   
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Definition", mappedBy="wordInWordlist")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="word_id", referencedColumnName="word_wordlist_word_id"),
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="wordlist_id", referencedColumnName="word_wordlist_wordlist_id")
     * })
     * @Expose()
     **/
    protected $definitions;


    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Wordlist", inversedBy="wordInWordlist")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="wordlist_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $wordlist;
```

The applicable part of the definition entity is below:

```
class Definition
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WordInWordlist", inversedBy="definitions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="word_wordlist_word_id", referencedColumnName="word_id"),
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="word_wordlist_wordlist_id", referencedColumnName="wordlist_id")
     * })
     **/
    protected $wordInWordlist;
```

### My Attempts

## 1

```
public function getDefinitions($wordlist_id, $word_id)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
      ->where('d.word_wordlist_word_id = :word_id')
      ->andWhere('d.word_wordlist_wordlist_id = :wordlist_id')
      ->setParameter('word_wordlist_word_id', $word_id)
      ->setParameter('word_wordlist_wordlist_id', $wordlist_id)
      ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Result:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: SELECT d FROM Spellingbee\Business\Entity\Definition d WHERE d.word_wordlist_word_id = :word_id AND d.word_wordlist_wordlist_id = :wordlist_id in /home/dporter/projects/list_management/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:41 Stack trace:
#0 /home/dporter/projects/list_management/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(483): Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::dqlError('SELECT d FROM S...')
#1 /home/dporter/projects/list_management/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(758): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->semanticalError('line 0, col 63 ...', Array)
#2 /home/dporter/projects/list_management/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(279): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->processDeferredPathExpressions(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\SelectStatement))
#3 /home/dporter/projects/list_management/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(351): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->getAST()
#4 /home/dporter/projects/lis in /home/dporter/projects/list_management/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php on line 63
```

## 2

```
public function getDefinitions($wordlist_id, $word_id)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
      ->where('d.wordInWordlist = :wordlist_id')
      ->setParameter('wordlist_id', array(
        'word' => $word_id,
        'wordlist' => $wordlist_id
        )
      )
      ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Results:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: A single-valued association path expression to an entity with a composite primary key is not supported. Explicitly name the components of the composite primary key in the query. in /home/dporter/projects/list_management/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:235 Stack trace:
#0 /home/dporter/projects/list_management/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/SqlWalker.php(676): Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::associationPathCompositeKeyNotSupported()
#1 /home/dporter/projects/list_management/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/AST/PathExpression.php(79): Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker->walkPathExpression(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\PathExpression))
#2 /home/dporter/projects/list_management/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/SqlWalker.php(2295): Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\PathExpression->dispatch(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker))
#3 /home/dporter/projects/list_management/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/SqlWalker.php in /home/dporter/projects/list_management/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php on line 235
```

---

### Question

How can I create a doctrine query to get the results I outlined above in the "What I am Attempting" section.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Doctrine does not allow for the query I was attempting (which seems quite basic). The only way to do it using DQL or the query builder is to join on the inverse table and filter by the appropriate fields.

So this is my final result:

```
public function getDefinitions($wordlist_id, $word_id)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
      ->innerJoin('d.wordInWordlist', 'w')
      ->where('w.wordlist = :wordlist')
      ->andWhere('w.word = :word')
      ->setParameters(array(
        'word' => $word_id,
        'wordlist' => $wordlist_id
        )
      )
      ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you try by this way, where the signature of your method is an array?

```
public function getDefinitions(array $ids)
{
 $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
  ->where('d.wordInWordlist IN (:wordlist_id)')
  ->setParameter('wordlist_id', $ids)
  ->getQuery();

 return $query->getResult();
}
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: This does not work. The IN clause is for fetching a collection of entities. It turns out that what I want accomplished is not Supported by Doctrine (Yet?). I Found the comment saying as much in the code.